# How can I make the :hover area of effect inside the element with the property?

Tags: html, css, position

Everything works, except that my mouse activates :hover when it passes over the area where the circle should be normally positioned (I'm altering position on CSS). How can I move the :hover area to where the circle is positioned?

```
html:
<div id="texto_circulo">
 <a href="facebook.com"><b>Outsourcing empresarial</b>
 <br>
  para hacer crecer 
 <br>
<b>tu negocio</b>
</a>
</div>



 css:
#tu-negocio a {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  font-size:2.2em;
  color:#fff !important;
  line-height:150%;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #009CDE;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:relative ;
  top:-10px;
  left:66%;
  z-index:1;
  opacity:0.7;
  filter:alpha(opacity=70); /* For IE8 and earlier */
  }


#tu-negocio a:hover {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  font-size:2.2em;
  color:#fff !important;
  line-height:150%;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #E22F05;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:relative ;
  top:-10px;
  left:66%;
  z-index:1;
  opacity:0.8;
  filter:alpha(opacity=80); /* For IE8 and earlier */
  }
```

Comment: I see no circle when testing this.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have an element with id tu-negocio. 
Try this:

```
 <div id="tu-negocio">
 <a href="facebook.com"><b>Outsourcing empresarial</b>
 <br>
  para hacer crecer 
 <br>
<b>tu negocio</b>
</a>
</div>
<style>
#tu-negocio a {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  font-size:2.2em;
  color:#fff !important;
  line-height:150%;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #009CDE;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:relative ;
  top:-10px;
  left:66%;
  z-index:1;
  opacity:0.7;
  filter:alpha(opacity=70); /* For IE8 and earlier */
  }


#tu-negocio a:hover {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  font-size:2.2em;
  color:#fff !important;
  line-height:150%;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #E22F05;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:relative ;
  top:-10px;
  left:66%;
  z-index:1;
  opacity:0.8;
  filter:alpha(opacity=80); /* For IE8 and earlier */
  }
</style>
```

Comment: I pasted another html, imagine that it is as you say, the hovering area is still partially outside of the circle.

Comment: @oespib On what browser are you testing it?